# Warning: Missing argument 1 for FM\ElFinderPHP\Connector\ElFinderConnector::run()

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

I'm working in a symfony project and I have a problem with browsing server in ckeditor for inserting images.
I'm using **"Trsteel/ckeditor-bundle": "~1.8"** and **"helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~4.0"**. When I try to browse the server to add image I have this error (Unable to connect to backend):

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
> FM\ElFinderPHP\Connector\ElFinderConnector::run(), called in
> C:\wamp\www\awb\vendor\helios-ag\fm-elfinder-bundle\Loader\ElFinderLoader.php
> on line 63 and defined

Here is my config.yml:

> trsteel_ckeditor: class: Trsteel\CkeditorBundle\Form\Type\CkeditorType
> transformers: [] toolbar: ['document', 'clipboard', 'editing', '/',
> 'basicstyles', 'paragraph', 'links', '/', 'insert', 'styles', 'tools']
> toolbar_groups: document: ['Source','-','Save','-','Templates']
> clipboard:
> ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo']
> editing: ['Find','Replace','-','SelectAll'] basicstyles:
> ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat']
> paragraph:
> ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','JustifyLeft',
> 'JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'] links:
> ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'] insert:
> ['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule'] styles: ['Styles','Format']
> tools: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks'] ui_color: '#ffffff'
> startup_outline_blocks: false width: 100% #Integer or % height: 300
>
> ## Integer or % language: 'fr'
>
> ## filebrowser_upload_url:
>
> ## url: relative-url.php?type=file filebrowser_image_browse_url: route: elfinder route_parameters: instance: default
>
> fm_elfinder: instances: default: locale: %locale%  editor: ckeditor
> fullscreen: true include_assets: true  connector: debug: false  roots:
>
> uploads: show_hidden: false driver: LocalFileSystem path: uploads
> upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'] upload_deny:
> ['all'] upload_max_size: 6M

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You should as suggested in [the issues of fe-elfindeer](https://github.com/helios-ag/ElFinderPHP/issues/22) to use the 5.0.5 version of ElFinderBundle who provides the 1st parameter to the ElFinderConnector::run() function.

Maybe you could try to edit your composer.json file as following :

"helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~5.0",
"helios-ag/fm-elfinder-php-connector": "~2.3"

**and run** composer update helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle helios-ag/fm-elfinder-php-connector

Comment: Thank you for you help,
I did it but it doesn't solve my problem. I got a blank page?

Any ideas?

Comment: just delete the cache and check the logs of symfony to get what's wrong